# Load iOS buttons dynamically with text from database. Xamarin.iOS c#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uibutton, xamarin

Dear fellow programmers.
Currently my strings are loaded, and 5 buttons are created with these titles from the database.
Yet the buttons are not visible on the iOS app.
What am I missing.
I am using Xamarin.iOS and c#

Thanks in advance

```
    using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Drawing;
using Ola.ServiceClients;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PortableRest;
using Ola.Shared.Models;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace Ola.iOS
{
    partial class NavigationViewController : UIViewController
    {

        //private MenuItem[] menuItems;
        private MenuItem[] drawerItems;
        public string token = "";

        public NavigationViewController(IntPtr handle)
            : base(handle)
        {
        }
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            LoadMenu();
        }



        public async void LoadMenu()
        {
            RestResponse<MenuItem[]> response = await NavigationClient.Current.GetMenu(token);

            //HttpResponseHeaders responseHeaders = response.HttpResponseMessage.Headers;
            //HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = response.HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage;

            if (response != null && response.Content != null && response.Content.Length > 0)
            {
                //menuItems = response.Content;

                for (int i = 0; i < response.Content.Length; i++)
                {
                    UIButton button = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
                    button.SetTitle(response.Content[i].Text, UIControlState.Normal);
                    this.Add(button);

                    System.Console.WriteLine("Button created");
                }
                System.Console.WriteLine();


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Greetings
Dave

Comment: try break the problem down. firstly can you create a button in LoadMenu(). try that before you even try pulling back titles from somewhere else. To add a view to the subview you should be calling View.AddSubview(button);

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to show your buttons:

```
this.View.AddSubview(button);
```

instead of:

```
this.Add(button);
```

Comment: That did not change anything. My console says 5 buttons are created ( since there are 5 database results ). But still no buttons visible

Comment: Are you sure that you add the buttons in the correct visible view?

Comment: I am doing the code in the ViewController that is paired with the UIViewController in the storyboard. So I assume it is the right view

Comment: The code above is the complete code from my class. No additional classes are used for this one

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting `button.Frame` property, adding button to parent View and also you should try to set background color as by default its transparent.
Edit
I'm not sure if that will make any difference but try to create buttons differently e.i
 `var button = new UIButton(new RectangleF());`
And one more thing I'm thinking of may be transparency, make sure that parent View and buttons do not have alpha set to 0
Edit 2
One more thing ! Try wrap call where you adding buttons to view by calling it in `InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
 {
     this.View.AddSubview(button);
 });`
method !

Comment: I did but its still not working button.Frame = new RectangleF(10, 20, 100, 32);